# Finding time complexity of this loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What's time complexity of this loop?

```
R = 40;
while(R>=10){
  x = x-1;
  R = R div 2;
}
```

I really appreciate if you explain it to me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cycle the R is reduced to half.

Therefore `O(log_2 R)`

---

If `R=40` cannot be changed, then the loop will just run 3 times therefore it is constant and `O(1)`

Comment: `R` is given a constant initial value in the algorithm shown; it’s not something that varies between runs.

Comment: @Sneftel - I think the R initial value is just an example and can change.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity will be **O(log<sub>2</sub>R)**.

Idea is that the R will get divided by 2 every time it enters the loop.
R/2, R/2<sup>2</sup>, R/2<sup>3</sup>...

At some point R/2<sup>x</sup> = 10.
So which equates to 2<sup>x</sup> = (R/10)
and x = log<sub>2</sub>(R/10).

Since this appears to be close to log<sub>2</sub>R we can say its ~ **O(log<sub>2</sub>R)**